# No results when looping through files in folder to find regex and sending to Excel - Using Python 3.6 and Xlsxwriter

Tags: python, loops, scripting, xlsxwriter

Before anything, I'd like to point out that I'm fairly new to python and programming as a whole so I apologize if I'm not being to clear in my question. If that is the case, just please let me know what I'm doing wrong and I will make alterations to my question.

**Quick Run Down:**

I have created a rather script that iterates through a whole bunch of TXT files( ~120 right now) within a specific folder directory. If the TXT files match certain conditions( `filename.endswith(" ")`) a loop is initiated, which is suppose to go into each individual text file and find all the emails via regex. With each instance of finding emails within a specific file, a list is created. Once all these emails are extracted (and their corresponding lists created),they are sent to Excel via xlsxwriter.

***Main Issue:***

There are NO emails/results when I open the excel file that is created! Also, no errors are produced when the script runs. This script works perfectly fine when I do it file by file(meaning that I use a text file's specific path instead of iterating through the whole folder). What am I doing wrong?

**Ideally(but not as important as the issue /\ ):**
I would like the script to create a Sheet within the newly created Workbook for every list, that way it is organized. I have about 120 TXT files in the folder thus far, but the files can be organized into groups based on file names (don't think it's practical to have over >50 sheets in a workbook). File names are shared as such...

> Client_Info_LA(1) , Client_Info_LA(2), Self_Info(1),Self_Info(2)

Thus organizing all Client_Info_LA in one sheet and Self_Info in another(was thinking of maybe using pandas to groupby). This isn't as important to me as actually getting the script to output the data I need into Excel, but if anyone knows how to tackle this it would really be helpful!

### Here's the script...

```
import re
import xlsxwriter
import os


'Create List of Lists'

n = len(os.listdir("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Emails_Project\\Txt_Emails"))
lists = [[] for _ in range(n)] #For stack peeps: Is the list of lists causing the issue?


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('TestEmails1.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()


'Find emails'
for filename in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Emails_Project\\Txt_Emails"):
    if filename.endswith(".txt") :

        for emails in filename:

            if re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", emails):
                lists.append(emails)
                worksheet.write_column('A2', lists)


    else:
        continue


workbook.close()
```

I have been searching through the web and have tried multiple things -- nothing has worked. This is truly my last resort so if anyone can give me some guidance, suggestions, or insight as to how to fix this, I would truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Mainly, there are two problems in the code provided.

- First, it doesn't open files. The variable `file_name` is a string (a list of characters). So, the for loop `for emails in file_name:` will iterate over the elements of the characters of the string `file_name`. Hence, `emails` is a character.
- Second, it overwrites what it has written before. `worksheet.write_column('A2', lists)` because you specify the same cell every time.

Here is a suggested code snippet that writes the emails found from different files to different columns in a same sheet.

```
import re
import xlsxwriter
import os
import codecs

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('TestEmails1.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

path = "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Emails_Project\\Txt_Emails\\"
row_number = 0
col_number = 0
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".txt") :
        file_handler = codecs.open(path+filename,'r', 'utf-8')
        file_contents = file_handler.read()
        found_mails = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", file_contents)
        if found_mails != [] :
            for mail in found_mails:
                worksheet.write(row_number, col_number, mail)
                row_number+=1
            row_number=0
            col_number+=1
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input abdullah! From the looks of it, the code seems exactly what I'm looking for. However, I have a UnicodeDecodeError that is popping up : UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 34532: character maps to <undefined> ..which is being produced in : line 14, in <module>
    file_contents = file_handler.read() ... do I have to change the encoder in file_handler?

Comment: This worked divinely... I really appreciate the help. Now, one last question(I swear!).. I'm attempting to put a remove_duplicates function but it's not removing the duplicates..def remove_duplicates(list):  return set(list) ...and the I'm calling it right underneath "row_number +=1" as remove_duplicates(mail)....Again, I'm sorry for such a simply question. Still just getting the hang of this...